# Tracing Code by Functions

Tags: c

I know the answers are a=0, b=10, and c=2 because I wrote it out and compiled it, but I'm unsure of how the answers were found.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int a, int b)
{
    int c;

    c=3*a-b;
    a=(c+17)%23;
    b=23%(a+5);

    return a-b+c;
}

int main()
{
    int a=7, b=3, c=2;

    a=f(c,b);
    b=f(a,c);
    printf("a=%d,b=%d,c=%d\n", a,b,c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like simple math.  What specifically are you unsure of?

Comment: What is the problem here ? This is just some simple math operations...

Comment: I must just be missing the point. I'm getting a=19, b=23, c=18 when I trace it by hand.

Comment: The argument values are not changed by the function

Comment: Are you sure you don't confuse the `c` in your main function with the `c` in your `f()`?

Comment: Use a debugger, it will help you to run step by step your program and so understand what do each line. Debugger is not only an useful tools to develop, but also to learn!

Comment: How do I find/use a debugger? You mean like a bunch of printf statements?

Comment: A debugger is more powerful than printf statements. It is a tool that lets you pause a running program and inspect its state, including variables and the function call stack. If you are on Linux I would recommend gdb. On Windows, whatever IDE you are using probably comes with a begubber along with it.

Comment: That said, right now this question is unfortunately very vague and its hard to give an answer for it because without knowing what is the specific problem you have there is no way to know if the details in the answer will be sufficient. If you still can't figure out the answer yourself, please edit your question to explain what exactly about this program you do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do this line by line -

a = f(c,b) -

```
c = 3 * a - b --> (3 * 2) - 3 = 3
a = (c+17) % 23 --> 20 % 23 = 20
b = 23 % (a+5) --> 23 % 25 = 23

return a - b + c --> 20 - 23 + 3 = 0
```

a = 0

b=f(a,c) -

```
c = 3 * a - b --> (3 * 0) - 2 = -2
a = (c+17) % 23 --> (-2 + 17) % 23 = 15
b = 23 % (a+5) --> 23 % 20 = 3

return a - b + c --> 15 - 3 + -2 = 10
```

b = 10

And c value remain 2

Answer (score 0):

The code is full of reassignments and superfluous initializations which makes the code unnecessarily hard to follow. If we rewrite it like this the computations will be easier to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int a, int b)
{
    const int c = 3 * a - b;
    const int d = (c + 17) % 23;
    const int e = 23 % (d + 5);

    return c + d - e;
}

int main(void)
{
    const int c = 2;
    const int a = f(c, 3);
    const int b = f(a, c);

    printf("a=%d,b=%d,c=%d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```